# is there a way to use a Scanner to set the number of dimensions in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

What I am trying to do is creating a list (array dimensions) with multiple groups (array rows), based on user input.
For example:

```
// get list number;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many lists do you want to create?");
int listNum = input.nextInt();

// listNum = 4
// create array with 4 dimensions;

// get  list size;
for (int i=0; i<listNum; i++) {
    System.out.println("How many entries are in list No."+(i+1)+" ?");
    // TBC
}
```

Comment: Are you sure an array with x dimension is a suitable data collection for your need here? It sounds rather impractical to create an array with that many dimensions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Comment: Do you mean create a custom 2d array? or custom any dimension array?

Comment: I agree with @bdehmer.  Based on the structure and questions in the code, I think they simply want a 2D array where each row has possibly a different number of entries; otherwise known as a [jagged array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jagged-array-in-java/).

Comment: I know you're learning, but lists are different than arrays here, and would not require the pre-filling that you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of creating a [jagged array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jagged-array-in-java/) of ints:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many lists do you want to create? ");
    int listNum = input.nextInt();

    int[][] data = new int[listNum][];

    // get number of entries for each row
    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("How many entries are in list No. "+(i+1)+" ? ");
        int numEntries = input.nextInt();
        data[i] = new int[numEntries];
    }

    // demonstrate that it worked:
    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<data[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(data[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
How many lists do you want to create? 3
How many entries are in list No. 1 ? 5
How many entries are in list No. 2 ? 7
How many entries are in list No. 3 ? 2
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do something like this, but it's nasty as hell. Assuming 4 is max.

```
int dim = input.nextInt(); //4
Object wtfarray = getArray(dim,2);
putAvalueOnFirstJustForFun(wtfarray,dim,-99);
//throw new Exception("Please kill me");

/*wtfarray 
    
    [[[[-99, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]], 
     [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]]
*/


//...
void putAvalueOnFirstJustForFun(Object array, int dim, int value)
{
  switch(dim)
  {
    case 1:  {((int[])array)[0] = value; return;}
    case 2:  {((int[][])array)[0][0] = value; return;}
    case 3:  {((int[][][])array)[0][0][0] = value; return;}
    //...until your max    
    default: {((int[][][][])array)[0][0][0][0] = value;}
}

static Object getArray(int dimensions, int size)
{
  switch (dimensions)
  {
     case 1:  {return new int[size];}
     case 2:  {return new int[size][size];}
     case 3:  {return new int[size][size][size];}
     //...until your max    
     default: {return new int[size][size][size][size];}
   }
}
```

**This thing is ugly, please do not do it.**

Comment: In reality, you could just abstract the actual math behind a contiguous array. If you want to add a dimension, it'll be another subdivision of your available indicies. (so, modulo and multiplying maths). Abstracting that to a class would then rid you of the infinite switch. Neat solution for something simple though (<10D)

Comment: @Rogue I think I've created one of the ugliest codes ever, you're being so benevolent with the term *Neat*    `; )`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are mixing up dimensions with rows... then you're on to it. Just capture the columns (for you `listNum`) then rows with another int variable. Then create the array like you normally would.

```
int[][] customArray = new int[listNum][rowNum];
```